# Unresolved external symbol already defined when creating class

Tags: c++, symbols

I'm struggling to understand why this symbol isn't defined altough it's defined in the main.cpp. Code is as following:

Memory Class:

```
#pragma once
#include "CrownIncludes.h"

class Memory {
public:
    template<typename T>
    inline T Read(std::uintptr_t ptrAddress) const
    {
        T val = T();

        ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, (LPCVOID)ptrAddress, &val, sizeof(T), NULL);
        return val;
    }
private:
    HANDLE procHandle = Settings::pHandle;
};
```

CrownIncludes.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Global.h"
using namespace Global; 

#include "Crown.h"
#include "Memory.h"
```

Crown.cpp:

```
#include "CrownIncludes.h"
//#include "Memory.h"

void Crown::Setup() {
    std::cout << "Crown loading..." << std::endl;
    Memory* MemoryManager = new Memory();

    DWORD LocalPlayer = 0x0;
    MemoryManager->Read(0x02C8 + 0x0390, LocalPlayer);
    std::cout << LocalPlayer << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
...
    std::cout << "Success! (" << TargetProcess->GetHandle() << ")" << std::endl;
    HANDLE pHandle = TargetProcess->GetHandle();

    // Main 
    Crown::Setup();
...
```

The error:

```
Fehler  LNK2001 Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""void * Global::Settings::pHandle" (?pHandle@Settings@Global@@3PEAXEA)" Crown.obj
```

When uncommenting Memory* MemoryManager = new Memory(); the code works though.
(So i'd guess the Memory Class can't find the pHandle)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured it out by now, but I'll answer regardless for future readers.

If you're using C++11(or later) and want to simply initialize `procHandle` to `null`:

```
// (Memory.h)
//...
HANDLE procHandle = nullptr;
```

And you're done.

I think you're confusing two different `pHandle` identifiers. There's a `pHandle` defined in `main()`, but it's a local variable, different from `Global::Settings::pHandle` that the error refers to. You haven't provided the code for the latter, so based on the error alone you haven't initialized it in `Global.cpp`
 or `Settings.cpp`(the cpp file for `Global::Settings`).

The fix is ensuring `Global::Settings::pHandle` is initialized in the relevant cpp file:

```
// (Global.cpp/Settings.cpp)
//...
HANDLE Global::Settings::pHandle = nullptr;
```

Alternatively, initialize it in-class:

```
// (Global.h/Settings.h)
//...
HANDLE pHandle = nullptr;
```

In `Memory.h`, you're initializing `procHandle` to `Settings::pHandle`, which based on the error and what you appear to be doing with it indicates that `Settings::pHandle` can't be constexpr. Data members can only be initialized in-class to constexpr values, otherwise you'll have to use a constructor because non-constexpr values will need to be read at runtime.

```
// If Settings::pHandle is constexpr. i.e. pHandle is a nullptr alias.
//...
    HANDLE procHandle = Settings::pHandle;
//...

// If Settings::pHandle is NOT constexpr.
//...
   Memory() :
       procHandle(Settings::pHandle) {}
//...
private:
    HANDLE procHandle;
//...
```